# Best way to save data in C# and restore data when program starts

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the best way to store data in a C# application?

I plan to have the user to set the database connection and output folder. But I need my application to remember those settings the next time the user starts the application.

I was thinking saving the data to an XML file then just extract the data from the XML file each time the application starts. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps Visual Studios' application settings?

Visual Studio -> Project -> (project name) Properties -> Settings tab

If it's the latter, how would I go about this?

Comment: You should be able to use your `app.config`.

Comment: You should mention if you're using UWP/WPF/WF etc.

Comment: query database and put into a datatable.  The use datatable method WriteXml().

Comment: Project > Properties > Settings tab.  Press F1 for help.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you definitely want to use the Properties.Settings. This will let you have user-specific connections easily.

You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456291/settings-settings-vs-app-config-in-net-desktop-app) for a good breakdown of each option.